# Changing CSS variables via JS in Polymer

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

In my Polymer project, I have a toolbar with a color I want to change using JavaScript. Since Polymer uses the CSS variable — paper-toolbar-background internally for styling, I can't do something like style.color. I found a method named `setProperty()`, but it doesn't work for me. Has anyone already found a solution?

Comment: Are you saying that you are using `paper-toolbar` and you are trying to set the `background-color` CSS property via JavaScript?

Answer (score 16):

Set the variable value in the element's customStyle map then call the updateStyle method.

Here is an example of an element that changes its own visibility by modifying the value of a custom style that it defines.  The variable can be external as well.

```
<dom-module id="my-elem">

  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      --my-elem-visibility: hidden;
    }
    #child {
       visibility: var(--my-elem-visibility)
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <div id="child">Some content goes here.</div>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
   Polymer({

      is: 'my-elem',

      setVisible: function (visible) {
          this.customStyle['--my-elem-visibility'] = 'visible';
          this.updateStyles();
      }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Check here for another answer that uses a bound data attribute to control a custom style: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739078/polymer-how-to-handle-a-style-dynamically/36743927#36743927

Comment: For future reference, this is now changed in Polymer 2 to a single line

`this.updateStyles({'--my-elem-visibility': 'visible'});`

Answer (score 4):

Basically,

1. Grab the element
2. Use the customStyle property to alter --paper-toolbar-background
3. Run element.updateStyles()

Please see the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#style-api). [Edit] If you need an example, I've one [here](http://polymerjs.newfivefour.com/post/126605117812/dynamically-changing-a-css-style).

Answer (score 1):

To set the CSS variable for the current `Polymer.Element`:

```
this.updateStyles({'--paper-toolbar-background': '#ed0'});
```

To set the variable globally use:

```
Polymer.updateStyles({'--paper-toolbar-background': '#ed0'});
```