# Polymer: how to handle a style dynamically

Tags: polymer

Hey i'm trying to create a simple drag and drop. Is that possible to style an element dynamically. My code will be more explicit:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="wireframe-view">
<template>
    <div on-tap="handleTap"
        style$=width:{{ width }}px; background-color:red;
     >Hello, World</div>    
</template>    


<script>    
    Polymer({
        is: "wireframe-view",
        handleTap: function() {
           this.width = 200;
        }
    });

</script>
```

This should change the width in my "style" propertie :/

Comment: This has been asked and answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996261/changing-css-variables-via-js-in-polymer/32015201#32015201

Comment: The other question is explicitly about changing a CSS variable. I don't think the answers apply for this question.

Answer (score 4):

If the property value contains spaces quotes are required.

```
style$="width:{{ width }}px; background-color:red";
```

Comment: Wait a second.... this works in polymer?  I didn't think polymer supported a binding embedded amidst other text?

Comment: That was added eventually https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#compound-bindings

Comment: well and it is buggy

Comment: It is? Actually I haven't used it myself. Even though I know it existed I stuck with the approach to only bind the full value instead of only a part.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method for dynamically updating the style based on the value of a bound data attribute.

```
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

    <dom-module id="conditional-css-example">

   <style>
     #tapContainer {
       width: 100px;
       background-color:white;
    }
     #tapContainer[data-tap-status$="tapped"] {
       width: 200px;
       background-color:red;
    }
   </style>

    <template>
        <div id="tapContainer" data-tap-status$="[[tapStatus]]" on-tap="handleTap">Tap Me!</div>    
    </template>    

    <script>    
        Polymer({
            is: "conditional-css-example",
            properties: {
              tapStatus: String;
            },
            handleTap: function() {
               this.tapStatus='tapped';
            }
        });    
    </script>
```