# Styling :host of Polymer Element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I want to style the `:host{}`, of a custom Polymer element, with Javascript (dynamically). The property I want to style is the "line-height", which will vary depending on the user's screen size (the text will always be on one line).

In an attempt to find a sulotion I have used two different methods: 
**The first is with normal jquery:**

```
   <dom-module is="custom-element">
        <template>
            <style>
                :host {
                    position: relative;
                    display: inline-block;
                    min-width: 5.15em;
                    min-height: 2em;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                    background: transparent;
                    font-size: 1.3em;
                    outline: none;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    color: #ABCFCA;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    text-align: center;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }
            </style>
            <content></content>
        </template>
        <script>
            Polymer({
                is: "custom-element",
                properties: {

                },
                ready: function() {
                    $(this).css("line-height", $(this).height() + "px");
                }
            });
        </script>
```

**The second method I tried is using Polymer's custom css properties:**

```
   <dom-module is="custom-element">
        <template>
            <style>
                :host {
                    position: relative;
                    display: inline-block;
                    min-width: 5.15em;
                    min-height: 2em;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                    background: transparent;
                    font-size: 1.3em;
                    outline: none;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    color: #ABCFCA;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    text-align: center;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    line-height: --dynamic-line-height;
                }
            </style>
            <content></content>
        </template>
        <script>
            Polymer({
                is: "custom-element",
                properties: {

                },
                ready: function() {
                    this.customStyle['--dynamic-line-height'] = $(this).height();
                    this.updateStyles();
                }
            });
        </script>
```

In the first method (plain jquery) when inspecting the element with Chrome's Element Inspector the `line-height` property isn't even added/set, and the text remains at the default vertical position

The second method ends up the same as the first method (no change/result in the element's style)

It should be noted that `console.log($(this).height());` produces the expected result of `32px` (on my screen)

It would be awesome if someone can help me either fix/edit any of my existing methods or provide me with a method that they have used/is documented somewhere.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS in the 2nd example only uses a CSS variable but doesn't declare one.
Declare one first like:

```
        <style>
            :host {
                --dynamic-line-height: 1px;
                ....
                line-height: var(--dynamic-line-height);
            }
        </style>

         ...

           ready: function() {
                var height = Polymer.dom(this).node.offsetHeight + 'px';
                this.customStyle['--dynamic-line-height'] = height;
                this.updateStyles();
            }
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/gLjgmqSUPuDqDEgHsZse?p=preview)

See also [Changing CSS variables via JS in Polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996261/changing-css-variables-via-js-in-polymer)

Comment: Thank You, I have done as you said - however `--dynamic-line-height` does not update, and no errors are thrown. Furthermore `$(this).height()` now returns an incorrect value for the height of the element - but going into the console and typing `$("#element_id").height()` gives the correct value

Comment: I'd try to move the variable declaration to a separate `:host {}` selector block. Try `Polymer.dom(this).height()`. If it doesn't work I'll trx in a Plunker later.

Comment: `Polymer.dom(this).height()` gives: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'height' in undefined`, and moving `--dynamic-line-height` to another `:host {}` gives `Uncaught TypeError: property.indexOf is not a function`

Comment: Wired. The code you supplied on Plunker does indeed work, but when I put that code into my code I still get the `Uncaught TypeError: property.indexOf is not a function` Error. Could this be a Polymer bug? Would it be better to ask this question on the Github Polymer Page?

Comment: I saw this error as well. It seems this is when Polymer doesn't find the CSS variable. Maybe something wrong with your CSS?

Comment: Odd. Using `this.style.lineHeight = "xxx"` works fine.

I also tried changing `line-height: var(--dynamic-line-height)` to `background: var(--dynamic-line-height)` and using `this.customStyle['--dynamic-line-height'] = "red";` and it all seems to work and update fine

Comment: Can you try to reproduce the problem in the Plunker?

Comment: I just tried, but the code seems to work fine in Plunker - even more odd, if I make a new html file containing only the plunker code it works fine. Could it be my HTML or CSS outside of the element interfering?

Comment: Hard to tell. Maybe a timing issue.

Comment: Well thank you for trying, For now I have found a different solution - not as ideal as using the variables but it will do for now. Thanks again

Comment: Instead of declaring `--dynamic-line-height: 1px;` it can also be passed as a default value `line-height: var(--dynamic-line-height, 1px);`